Auth0 change default loading display which briefly shows after confirming email but before redirect to app
everyone,
I’m working with Auth0 for email verification on a custom domain. After users click the verification button in the email, they are briefly redirected to the URL myCustomAuth0Domain/u/email-verification?ticket=someRandomToken where auth0 confirms email, and then to the URL specified in the "Redirect To" setting in email branding.
I’m using the Universal Login with a custom template, and I would like to customize the appearance of the Auth0 /u/email-verification page, as it currently looks like this:enter image description here
I’ve searched through all the settings and the Auth0 forums but haven’t found useful information on how to modify this page’s look.
Is there a way to customize the design of the Auth0 email verification page? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
